# D3.js error using timescale (path is NaN)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Im using d3.js to make a heatmap. My data is an object out of which i have pulled out the maximum and minimum year. When i use `d3.timeScale()` to initialise my x axis, im getting an error with all my years rendering on the same position of x ( this is due to the following errors on the console)

`d3.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,6V0.5HNaNV6".
(anonymous) @ d3.min.js:2
13d3.min.js:2 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,0)".`

Some of the code which involves making the time scale and the axis is shown here

```
const MIN_DATE = new Date(MIN_YEAR, 0),
    MAX_DATE = new Date(MAX_YEAR, 0);

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE])
    .range(0, WIDTH);

 var svg = d3.select('.chart')
    .attr('width', WIDTH + margins.left + margins.right)
    .attr('height', HEIGHT + margins.top + margins.bottom);

var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');

g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + HEIGHT + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

Im wondering what is causing this error ,i've made something similar earlier but the only difference i had there was that i was passing the Date as a string to my Date constructor, here i have the value as years.

```
{
year: 2012,
month: 3,
variance: 0.703
},
Im using the year in as my `MIN_YEAR`, which i recieve through an API call. The year is a number. `MIN_YEAR` and `MAX_YEAR` are being assigned correctly.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In D3 scales, you have to pass an array to `range`. The API is clear:

> If range is specified, sets the scale’s range to the specified **array** of values. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, it should be:

```
.range([0, WIDTH]);
```

Comment: thank you. one of those things which you tend to oversee, i was diving too deep into the issue and neglected that i was missing the square brackets