# d3 time axis NaN error

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to make a simple line chart in d3 v5 and I'm having trouble with the x axis.

Here's a sample of my data

```
{
"2015-05-02":"1",
"2015-05-03":"2",
"2015-05-04":"1",
"2015-05-13":"3",
"2015-05-15":"2",
"2015-05-16":"2",
"2015-05-20":"1",
"2015-05-26":"11",
"2015-05-27":"1",
"2015-05-28":"7",
"2015-05-29":"260",
}
```

Here I try to parse my keys as date objects

```
//attempting to parse dates
//the dates are strings (eg. 2015-02-18)
dates = d3.keys(data);
$.each(dates, function(thisDate){
  var formatDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  dates[thisDate] = formatDate(dates[thisDate]);
});
```

After looping through my dates, they are date objects that look like this:

```
Wed Feb 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

Then I set my mins and maxs:

```
minDate = d3.min(dates); //Wed Feb 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
maxDate = d3.max(dates); //Sat Dec 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

And set my scale like this:

```
//x scale
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([minDate,maxDate])
  .range(0,width);
```

Then I tried to display my axis like this

```
//x axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
svg.append('g')
  .call(xAxis);
```

It's currently giving me this error when I try to call the x axis:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,6V0.5HNaNV6".
```

My path wants numbers? But I just made them javascript date objects. I used to dabble in d3 v3, but I'm pretty rusty. Any links to good v5 examples would also be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Where is your data?

Comment: you set `dates` to the array of keys of dates, then you iterate over this array and at the same time you modify this array, this asks for problems. look at  the domain of your xAxis `xAxis.domain()`

Comment: @ksav I added a sample of my data to the question

Comment: @rioV8 xAxis.domain() is saying that's not a function. Do axes have domains? My xScale has a domain. When I console log it, it looks like this:

 [Wed Feb 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), Sat Dec 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)]

Just an array with my min and max. That's what I want, right?

Comment: Oops - yes `xScale.domain()`, that domain looks good. Is it really the xAxis path with the error?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you parse the dates like this

```
var formatDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var dates = d3.keys(data).map( d => formatDate(d) );

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(dates))
  .range([0,width]);
```

```js
var data = {
"2015-05-02":"1",
"2015-05-03":"2",
"2015-05-04":"1",
"2015-05-13":"3",
"2015-05-15":"2",
"2015-05-16":"2",
"2015-05-20":"1",
"2015-05-26":"11",
"2015-05-27":"1",
"2015-05-28":"7",
"2015-05-29":"260"
};
var width = 500;

var formatDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var dates = d3.keys(data).map( d => formatDate(d) );

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(dates))
  .range([0,width]);
  
console.log('xScale-domain', xScale.domain());
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8 , that's much cleaner. The error was coming from the range. I forgot the square brackets. -_-

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the square brackets on my range...

```
//x scale
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
   .domain([minDate,maxDate])
   .range(0,width);
```

Should have been

```
//x scale
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
     .domain([minDate,maxDate])
     .range([0,width]);
```

Shout out to this post for the answer: [D3.js error using timescale (path is NaN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198038/d3-js-error-using-timescale-path-is-nan)

Now on to the next problem...